# Where MAPI fields of mails are stored

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office, exchange-server, mapi

I was trying to programatically achieve Communication thread tracking for Outlook. I have found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx) article on MSDN. And I fiddled with it a bit. It seems that it is possible to do it by tracking `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` by developing Outlook Add In.

However I would like to achieve the similar functionality in Java. Since I am quite new to MAPI development, I was not quite clear about where this `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` is stored in `.msg` file or somewhere in Exchange server that we access using MAPI.

- I want to know if it is possible to intercept any incoming / outgoing message and obtain its `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` using Java. If `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` is stored in `.msg` file then I must be able to parse such file in Java and obtain the same.
- If it is not stored in `.msg` file then I will like to know where it is stored and how can I access using Java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Extended MAPI header files were ever translated to Java. 
Use C++ (or Delphi).

Comment: Hey thanks, can u please explain where this `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` and similar MAPI properties are stored? In `.msg` file or somewhere inside Outlook client and Exchange server? I have found [this](http://goo.gl/7g0HXt) which explains in more details about how this property is stored in protocol. However **I want to know where these bits are exactly stored physically?** Because if it is stored somewhere in the header of `.msg` file then I will try binary parsing the file in Java and interpreting it to obtain the `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX`. Am new to MAPI & didnt completely got it. Please help.

Comment: ohh god and I just realized u r the author of OutlookSpy. God damn awesome tool it is. Kudos to you boss.